# Cocoa Touch: Mask ignored when image is rendered: renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, rendering, mask, uibezierpath

I am trying to render a masked view using `renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()`. I am masking a white colored view which is the subView of a gray colored view. This works just fine for display: I end up with a white shape against a gray background, but when I render the mask is ignored, and all I see is white in the resulting image.

Mask in a UIView subclass

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
        CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
        CGMutablePathRef patheToMask = CGPathCreateMutable();
        CGRect scrollMaskRect = CGRectMake(30, 30, 100, 100);
        UIBezierPath *scrollMask = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:scrollMaskRect cornerRadius:30];
        CGPathAddPath(patheToMask, nil, scrollMask.CGPath);
        [maskLayer setPath:patheToMask];
        CGPathRelease(patheToMask);
        self.layer.mask = maskLayer;
}
```

render code

```
-(void)renderImage {
    CGSize renderSize = CGSizeMake(masterView.frame.size.width, masterView.frame.size.height);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(renderSize);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSaveGState(context);
    CGContextConcatCTM(context, [[masterView layer] affineTransform]);
    [[masterView layer] renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    renderedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    CGContextRestoreGState(context);
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(renderedImage, self, @selector(image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);
    masterView.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
}
```

Here is the project http://owolf.net/uploads/StackOverflow/MaskWeirdness.zip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation, renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() does not support  masking.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html

From the docs:

> Important: The OS X v10.5 implementation of this method does not
>   support the entire Core Animation composition model.
>   QCCompositionLayer, CAOpenGLLayer, and QTMovieLayer layers are not
>   rendered. Additionally, layers that use 3D transforms are not
>   rendered, nor are layers that specify backgroundFilters, filters,
>   compositingFilter, or a mask values. Future versions of OS X may add
>   support for rendering these layers and properties.